# WPF/threading: Dispatcher static vs Dispatcher on a control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a bit confused in terms of the dispatcher. Say I'm on a background thread doing some kind of long operation. I'd like to update the ui thread I understand I do this through the dispatcher. My question is, do i call the dispatcher statically like: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(mywork) ... Or on the control i want to update: mytextbox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(mywork)

Answer (score 17):

It's worth noting that calling `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` *isn't* a static call: it's an implicit `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.  If you can use this call, you're likely writing your code from within a control or window already.  In that case, you're *probably* safe to call either since most of the time there will be one UI thread per application.

The actual static call would be `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke`, which is *not* something you want to call (see my comment on Hasan Khan's answer for why).

**EDIT:** Calling `Application.Current.Dispatcher` is *not* a bad thing.  (And, for clarity, it's an instance property, not a static - being called on a static/singleton instance of `Application`.)  This property will return the Dispatcher for the thread that the app was created with, and typically that's the thread that the UI is created on aswell - so `Application.Current.Dispatcher` returns the same Dispatcher as `myWindow.Dispatcher` would.

The static call `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` (that I warned against) returns a Dispatcher for the thread you call it from.  If you call it from a background thread, you'll get a new Dispatcher created especially for that thread - which often isn't what's wanted.

Comment: *Why* is using `Application.Current.Dispatcher` a bad idea? I use it in my application with no problems so far. All it requires is for `Application().Run()` to have been called.

Comment: @Aphex: I've answered as an edit since I couldn't fit it in the comment - but there's nothing wrong with `Application.Current.Dispatcher` (and I hadn't said that there was).  `Application.Current.Dispatcher` and `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` behave very differently!

Comment: There are cases where using Application.Current.Dispatcher is not safe (albeit very rare), e.g. hosting WPF control in WinForms (or any other non-WPF) app (Application.Current is null) or having multiple UI-threads wihin same app (there are a lot of troubles with shared app resources, but the case is still relevant). Therefore the safest way is to use control.Dispatcher

Answer (score 2):

First I think it is important to understand, that the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) is not designed to handle big background operations. It is designed to queue work on the UI thread of an object. Here is a worthwhile MSDN article about the .NET threading model and [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx):

- [Threading Model, Overview and the Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx#threading_overview)

Saying that the standard way of implementing the [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx) method would be to call it on the control:

```
startStopButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Normal, new NextPrimeDelegate(CheckNextNumber)
);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

While in *most* cases using either `DispatcherObject.Dispatcher` (all dependency objects and controls inherit from `DispatcherObject`, among others) or `Application.Current.Dispatcher` is the right thing to do, as there's usually only one UI thread, there can be multiple UI threads and different windows can use different dispatchers. In that case, it's important to update the control using its dispatcher. It's stored in in its `Dispatcher` property (inherited from `DispatcherObject`), any other control in this window and the window itself.