# Cannot access non-static method in static context?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Given this code....

```
public class CalibrationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private FileSystemWatcher fsw;

    public CalibrationViewModel(Calibration calibration)
    {
        fsw = new FileSystemWatcher
            {
                Path = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Path\ToFile\Test_1234.txt",
                Filter = @"Test_1234.txt",
                NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite
            };

        fsw.Changed += (o, e) =>
            {
                var lastLine = File.ReadAllLines(e.FullPath).Last();
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<string>) WriteLineToSamplesCollection, lastLine); //line that cites error
            };
    }

    private void WriteLineToSamplesCollection(string line)
    {
        // do some work
    }
}
```

Why am I getting the error, 'Cannot access non-static method BeginInvoke in static context'?

I have looked at several other examples on SE and most cite trying to use a field before the object is created as if they were trying to use a non-static field in a static manner, but I don't understand what it is about my code that is invoking the same error.

Lastly, what can I do to fix this specific issue/code?

Update: Fixed title to reflect issue with a 'method' and not a 'property'. I also added that the class implements ViewModelBase.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If this is WPF, `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher` does not have a static `BeginInvoke()` method.

If you want to call that statically (this is, without having a reference to the Dispatcher instance itself), you may use the static `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` property:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(...etc);
```

Be aware though, that doing this from a background thread will NOT return a reference to the "UI Thread"'s Dispatcher, but instead create a NEW Dispatcher instance associated with the said Background Thread.

A more secure way to access the "UI Thread"'s Dispatcher is via the use of the `System.Windows.Application.Current` static property:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...etc);
```

Comment: Note that you can use WPF without any `Application` object, in which case `Application.Current` is `null`, meaning the more secure way isn't going to work.

Comment: @hvd Right, however that should happen only in exceptional cases (such as hosting WPF content in a winforms app). Otherwise going regular WPF applications and not having an instance of the `Application` class brings a lot of issues (such as this, and resources-related stuff).

Comment: Sure, agreed. And even in that case, if some code needs an `Application` object, it's possible to explicitly create one in the entry point, which will work just fine.

Comment: @HighCore The method `WriteLineToSamplesCollection(string line)` is responsible for updating an `ObservableCollection<T>` that the view is bound to. So do I need to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`?

Comment: @IsaiahNelson I'm not sure if the `FileSystemWatcher` fires it's events in a background thread, if so, yes. You can go with `Application.Current.Etc`.

Comment: It does fire them on a thread from the pool unrelated to the thread that controls the UI from what I have [read](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/FileSystemWatcher.aspx). See the section on Cross-Threading

Comment: @IsaiahNelson, right, then you should go ahead with the `Application.Current` approach.

Answer (score 9):

Change this:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
```

to this:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke
```

the issue is `BeginInvoke` is an instance method and needs an instance to access it. However, your current syntax is trying to access `BeginInvoke` in a `static` manner off the class `Dispatcher` and that's what's causing this error:

> Cannot access non-static method BeginInvoke in static context

Answer (score 3):

It's because `Dispatcher` is a class not a property. Shouldn't you be making your `CalibrationViewModel` class a subclass of some other class which has a `Dispatcher` property?

Comment: Well the CalibrationViewModel does implement a ViewModelBase for INPC and other items.

Comment: That's not what your code shows - public class CalibrationViewModel - you're not declaring any interface implementation there.