# Gameloop Thread dynamically made objects cannot be accessed in view

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, object, dispatcher

in C# WPF I have a game in which I load up the game with a thread and at the END it starts the gameloop thread. All good and well.

BUT: When the gameloop thread dynamically makes Projectile (Projectile extends Image) objects things go south. First i get: Thread must be STA because many UIComponents require this. so i set the appartmentstate. then, when i pass the object to the view and try to add it to the children off the canvas by this method:

```
public void addBaseElement(Image projectile)
{
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            myCanvas.Children.Add(projectile);

        }));
}
```

I get this error: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

On every similar question on this site the answer to this error is: just add:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
             //Your code here

}));
```

and it will be fine, and that helps sometimes. but in this case, it doesn't solve it.
Any suggestions?

EDIT: Marked duplicate with question that has the following solution:

**Make the dynamically created objects in the view Thread**
I am sorry, but this is not a sufficient solution to this problem, if I do this, the whole architecture of my project will have to change. The dynamically created objects must be created within the gameloop thread. This according to me is the only way to do it clean and with a nice architecture.

Comment: `if I do this, the whole architecture of my project will have to change` Unfortunate, but sometimes you have to do that.

Comment: This is helping me no further :|

Answer (score -2):

Did you investigate ->

```
SynchronizationContext.Current.Post
```

Which JarredPar suggests in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732709/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it).

EDIT: I was just about writing that you should create the UI elements on the UI (main - gameloop) thread when I saw your edit to the question ;) But I think that's the only way you can go. If your images come in from another thread you maybe have to reinstantiate / duplicate them on the UI thread and add them to the Canvas. This will cause overhead, sorry.

Comment: I've just tried it and it doesn't work, sorry