# Are Timer and Task creating new threads?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, task

In my app, when a `Button` is clicked a `Command` is triggered that downloads  the `image` (asynchronously.. I hope) and the `strings`, `name` and `character`, specified below. The function to download these items is called from a `DispatcherTimer` as such:

```
timer.Tick += myMethodToDownloadCastInfo;
```

Within this method I have:

```
 timer.Stop();
 List<CastWithPic> castWithPicList = new List<CastWithPic>();
 // Add name and id for each CastWithPic in the list
 // ..

 _viewModel.SelectedItem.castInfoWithPics = castWithPicList; 

// Download all the required pics
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (CastWithPic cast in castWithPicList)
{
   tasks.Add(downloadBitmap(cast.profilePath, cast.id));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Within the `downloadBitmap` function I set the object `SelectedItem's` `castInfoWithPics` to hold the `image` value.

It is at this point that I am receiving the error:

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

`SelectedItem` is declared in my `ViewModel`.

`SelectedItem` Class

```
public List<CastWithPic> castInfoWithPics { get; set; }
```

`CastWithPic` Class

```
public string name
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(nameProperty); }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(nameProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty nameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                            "name", typeof(string),
                                                            typeof(CastWithPic));

    public string character
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(characterProperty); }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(characterProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty characterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                            "character", typeof(string),
                                                            typeof(CastWithPic));

    public Bitmap image
    {
        get { return (Bitmap)this.GetValue(imageProperty); }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(imageProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty imageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                            "image", typeof(Bitmap),
                                                            typeof(CastWithPic));
```

`downloadBitmap`

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
RequestState myRequestState = new RequestState();
myRequestState.request = request;

// Start the asynchronous request.
IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RespCallback), Tuple.Create(myRequestState, actorID));

// this line implements the timeout, if there is a timeout, the callback fires and the request becomes aborted
ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(result.AsyncWaitHandle, new WaitOrTimerCallback(TimeoutCallback), request, DefaultTimeout, true);

// The response came in the allowed time. The work processing will happen in the  
// callback function.
allDone.WaitOne();
```

My question is:

Why don't I get an error when I assign, `_viewModel.SelectedItem.castInfoWithPics = castWithPicList;` in the `timer` method but I get an error in the `Task` method.

Isn't the `timer` also starting a new `thread`?

In this case is the proper way to resolve the issue to use the solution suggested here?

[The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732709/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it)

Comment: what does your `downloadBitmap` function look like?

Comment: Hi @NedStoyanov, I've added the `downloadBitmap` function.

Comment: Where do you set `SelectedItem` is it `RspCallback`?

Comment: @NedStoyanov `SelectedItem` is set in my `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `_viewModel.SelectedItem.castInfoWithPics = castWithPicList` needs to be set in the UI thread. Your `donloadBitmap` funciton uses a callback to process the response and that runs on a `ThreadPool` thread.

You can use `Dispatcher.Invoke` to force work to occur on a UI thread. Try putting this in your callback and putting the appropriate code in the commented section:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( 
  DispatcherPriority.Background,
  new Action(() => /* set selected item */));
```

For a better solution you can use `async-await` which restores the current `SynchronizatonContext` and yo do not need to use `Dispatcher.Invoke`. `HttpClient` provides an async friendly API you can use.

Here is a simple example setting a TextBox value.

```
 private async Task DownloadUrlAsync(string url)
 {
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        textBox1.Text = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
    }            
 }
```

Comment: It's a good guess.  Hard to say for sure when the OP didn't provide the necessary details, like which timer object he is using or what the error message is.

Answer (score -2):

You have to freeze your object and the problem is solved.
Here is a sample:

```
videoIcon = new BitmapImage();
videoIcon.BeginInit();
videoIcon.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Data\Image1.jpg");
videoIcon.DecodePixelWidth = 14;
videoIcon.EndInit();
videoIcon.Freeze();
```

Without the Freeze() I received the same error message you received. With Freeze() the problem is solved.
More info is here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509(v=vs.110).aspx
"A frozen Freezable can also be shared across threads, while an unfrozen Freezable cannot."

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the OP's problem.

Comment: Robert Harvey, you seem to be an export and maybe you are right. But I had a similar problem and after considerable research I found the Freeze() solution which worked for me. Maybe Giri can try to freeze the images and let us know if this solves the problem.