# Calling thread cannot access object due to separate thread ownership

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous

So I need to update my WPF UI and here is the code for the same. This updates and element in the UI. 
The `commandPrompt` object is created using a third party UI library noted here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247280/WPF-Command-Prompt. I was testing this UI mockup.
And it throws the exception below:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

```
 private void CommandProcess(object sender, ConsoleReadLineEventArgs EventArgs)
        {
            string[] command = new string[EventArgs.Commands.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < EventArgs.Commands.Length; i++)
            {
                command[i] = EventArgs.Commands[i].ToLower();
            }
            if (command.Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {                    
                    switch (command[0])
                    {
                        case "clear":
                            ProcessClear(command);
                            break;
                        case "demo":
                            ProcessParagraph(command);
                            break;

                        default:
                            new Task(() => { TextQuery(command); }).Start();                         
                            break;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    WriteToConsole(new ConsoleWriteLineEventArgs("Console Error: \r" + ex.Message));
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the TextQuery method. This uses the `RestSharp.dll` to communicate.

```
private void TextQuery(string[] command)
    {
        string APIQuery = ConvertStringArrayToString(command);

        USBM usbm = new USBM("XXXXXX");

        QueryResult results = usbm.Query(APIQuery);
        if (results != null)
        {
            foreach (Pod pod in results.Pods)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pod.Title);
                if (pod.SubPods != null)
                {
                    foreach (SubPod subPod in pod.SubPods)
                    {
                EXCEPTION?? ====>WriteToConsole(new ConsoleWriteLineEventArgs("" + subPod.Title + "\n" + subPod.Plaintext));

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the function that is used to write to the same custom console.

```
private void WriteToConsole(ConsoleWriteLineEventArgs e)
{
            commandPrompt.OnConsoleWriteEvent(this, e); <=======EXCEPTION HERE
}
```

How can I let the threads share the data amongst them? I Google it but really couldn't get I it to work as I am new to async coding.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to post more code. It seems you need to use the Dispatcher to invoke some work on the UI thread.

Comment: which line throws exception?

Comment: Added some details. Please tell if more is required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732709/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `WriteToConsole` calls `commandPrompt`, which accesses UI elements, that call should be made on the UI thread.

Since you use `Task`, you end up using another thread to invoke the UI from. That is not allowed and will give you the error you get.

You should call `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` to make the call on the UI thread:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
( new Action(() => 
      WriteToConsole(new ConsoleWriteLineEventArgs(subPod.Title + "\n" + subPod.Plaintext)))
, DispatcherPriority.Background
);
```

Comment: Can you show some code? I couldn't seem to make it work?