# "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it" error in C# WPF Application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm making a downloader application. There are main window and downloader classes named Main.xaml.cs and Downloader.cs in my project.

There is a custom ListBox in the main window. I'm trying to refresh the Listbox item from the Downloader.cs, but the application gives the "*The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns*" error.

**Downloader.cs:**

```
namespace MyDownloaderApp
{
    class Downloader
    {
        /*
        ...
        */

        private void doWork()
        {
            ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).myListBox.Items.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

**I got the following error:**

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll but was not handled in user code: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: The proper way to do this is to use bindings rather than to manipulate the listbox directly. And [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh140164.aspx) will be useful.

Comment: I'm already using binding. I want to refresh the listbox items after the adding data to listbox.

Comment: Well, then use an `ObservableCollection` along with `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` and it will update itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use :

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        ...// your code refresh listbox Items
    }));
```

please have a look at : [The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732709/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it)

Comment: You can use `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` instead of `this.Dispatcher.Invoke`.