# How to update GUI controls from an Excel interop event thread?

Tags: c#, excel, multithreading, office-interop

I've got a C# GUI applications that automates some Excel tasks via the official officer interop COM libraries. I'm providing my own event handler for the [`SheetActivate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.appevents_event.sheetactivate.aspx) event.

```
// fetch the excel handle
var excel = viewer.GetApplication() as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;

// set sheet activate event handler
excel.SheetActivate += excel_SheetActivate;
```

I believe that the interop libraries call this event handler from a thread that it has created. My issues is that I need to update some GUI components based on this event, but I cannot perform update operations on the GUI across these threads.

My question is, from this excel interop event handler, which I believe is in its own thread, how can I safely update my GUI in a thread safe way?

I ask this because I am receiving run-time errors about cross thread operations while updating the GUI, currently.

Edit: I believe the linked and suggested possible answers are for WPF. My application is not WPF, it is the older WinForms. I do not see an `Application.Current` property.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732709/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it

Comment: Thanks for the link. That does seem to point me in the correct direction, but those answers seem to be for WPF. I'm using the older WinForms. I do not see an `Application.Current` property.

Comment: @Ryan just use `someControl.Invoke(` from the control that is throwing the error, that will invoke the code on on the correct thread for that control.

Comment: Ah ok, gotcha. Thanks!

Comment: Turned my comment in to a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
private void excel_SheetActivate(object activatedSheet)
{
    if (someControl.InvokeRequired)
    {
        someControl.Invoke((WorkbookEvents_SheetActivateEventHandler)excel_SheetActivate, activatedSheet);
    }
    else
    {
        someControl.Text = //...
    }
}
```

where `someControl` is the control that is throwing the error, that will check to see if a invoke is necessary, and if it is it will re-call the same function with the same arguments on the correct thread for that control.