# Updating Image.source from a separate thread in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am building a WPF program that does some image acquisition, processing and displaying with a Image object. Currently I summon new a thread from c++ to do the acquisition and processing, then update the Image through callbacks.

It seems when I access the Image.source in the callback, it throws a exception of something like "cannot access this object because another thread own it". I tried to construct the Image and access the Image.source both in the STA thread but the same exception occurs. How should I deal with this?

Much appreciated.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33917169) in particular, in the marked duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create an ImageSource on a background thread, you can call its `Freeze` method to make it cross-thread accessible.

You would then set the `Source` property of an Image control in the UI thread, by calling `Dispacher.Invoke`:

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
...
bitmap.EndInit();
bitmap.Freeze();

image.Source.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => image.Source = bitmap);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
 if (InvokeRequired)
 {
    this.Invoke(new Action<source>(ImageObject), new object[] {value});
    return;
 }
```

OR

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
MainForm.UpdateImageSource(source); 
});
```

OR

`Call Image.source = object`

Comment: Sorry, what is "Call"? It does not look like a valid keyword in C#.

Comment: that was the last resort, I am sorry, that is a vb.net keyword, try the options above it

Comment: idk what objects and data youre dealing with as you did not publish any code. so I gave source and image object as ideas, fill in the appropriate data