# Updating a image source on WPF .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, .net-6.0

I want to build an application and part of the functionality is to display a picture that is generated in the code. I can generate the picture and create the new source, I've read how to replace it from the ViewModel but it doesn't display. To replicate the issue I wrote the minimal application. Am I missing something? I have a previous application that works with code behind on a similar manner, replacing the source of the picture by a new `BitmapImage` in a `Invoke` of the dispatcher and that works.

ViewModel

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace TestImgs.ViewModels;

public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public BitmapImage RedImg { get; set; } = null;
    public BitmapImage BlueImg { get; set; } = null;
    public BitmapImage GreenImg { get; set; } = null;
    public ICommand RenderCmd { get; set; }

    private readonly Dispatcher dispatcher;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
        RenderCmd = new RelayCommand(Render);
    }

    public void Render()
    {
        dispatcher.Invoke(() => RedImg = GetSolidImg(Color.Red));
        dispatcher.Invoke(() => BlueImg = GetSolidImg(Color.Blue));
        dispatcher.Invoke(() => GreenImg = GetSolidImg(Color.Green));
    }

    private static BitmapImage GetSolidImg(Color color)
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(1024, 1024);
        using var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        using var brush = new SolidBrush(color);
        gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 1024, 1024);
        using var stream = new MemoryStream();
        bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        stream.Position = 0;
        var img = new BitmapImage();
        img.BeginInit();
        img.StreamSource = stream;
        img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        img.EndInit();
        img.Freeze();
        return img;
    }
}
```

And the view

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestImgs.Views.MainPage"
    Style="{DynamicResource MahApps.Styles.Page}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:TestImgs.Properties"
    xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:TestImgs.ViewModels" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vms:MainViewModel}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="48" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Render squares" Command="{Binding Path=RenderCmd}" />
        <Grid
            Grid.Row="1"
            Background="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Gray10}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Path=RedImg, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Path=BlueImg, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Image Grid.Column="2" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Path=GreenImg, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

My code is the same to other online solutions like [Updating Image.source from a separate thread in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893536/updating-image-source-from-a-separate-thread-in-wpf).

Comment: If you are not getting an exception the code is working but the view is not getting repainted.  Try a refresh : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/how-to-refresh-a-page?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: You are not using the ObservableObject base class correctly. As can be seen in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject), you have to write property setters that call the SetProperty method. Otherwise the PropertyChanged event of the implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface is not fired. Alternatively, set the [ObservableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty) attribute on a field in the view model class.

Comment: There is also some redundancy in your code. You could directly create a WriteableBitmap and fill it with a solid color instead of creating a WinForms Bitmap. The Render method could make a single Invoke call instead of three. It is however unclear why Dispatcher invocations should be made at all when the Render method is only called from RenderCmd - which should already be invoked in the UI thread.

Comment: You should also not be using `Application.Current.Dispatcher` in a view model, because a view model should have no knowledge of an Application class that is part of the view. Ideally, a view model would also not have knowledge of the Dispatcher class, because that is also part of the view - i.e. the view's UI framework.

Comment: It is also redundant to set `Mode=OneWay` on the Image Source Bindings, because OneWay is the default value.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks! Has been sometime since I last used WPF, you made me remember a lot of things.