# Can't access listbox from random method in code behind (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listbox

[works  here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb2zd.png) -----
[crashes here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV1Mv.png) ----- 
So i am making this server client chat system based on message queue and in client side, i have a thread that receives messages. The name of my listbox is 'displaymsg'

here's my thread pool method

```
public void getmsg(object ob)
    {
        string msg = "";

        while (true)
        {
            msg = mRecieve.GetMessages();
            displaymsg.Items.Add(msg);
        }
    }
```

But the program is crashing when it reaches to displaymsg.Items.Add(msg) part.
To check if it is even reaching there and if it is working fine, i replaced it with `MessageBox.Show(msg)`, and it is working fine, i receive every message in a pop up box that i send from other end. I'm new to wpf so kinda lost now... please help!!

Comment: What message do you receive in the non-working case? I suspect this is due to trying to access the control from the wrong thread but without the error message I can't be sure of that.

Comment: It doesn't show any error messages. Just crashes saying "client has stopped working, windows is reporting this problem"

Comment: @Shrey Is your while loop in your program actually written like that? while(true) goes on infinitely.  If you're creating infinite amounts of items to be added its going to crash because you're consuming all the computer resources.

Comment: Actually for sake of making it work first, i dont have loop at all. i just do
string msg = "";
displaymsg.Items.Add("something here");

it crashes when i use displaymsg, but works when i use messagebox.

Comment: Another thing is, i have made this method public void getmsg(), but when i do static void getmsg(), i don't get access to displaymsg at all. While having public method, i can atleast access it, though it crashes, but when i make this method static, i can't even access it.

Comment: @Shrey Please post some more code so we know whats going on.  From the example we cant deduce anything too specific to help you figure out the problem.

Comment: Are you running your program in the debugger? Debugged apps don‘t just crash without a message.

Comment: Okay i just ran it in debugger and it says, System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'

Comment: i have just uploaded two pictures of my code... please check above

Comment: You run it in the debugger yet get the" reporting this error" behavior? And there is no useful message at the bottom of the debug output window (found at the view menu -> output in VS).

Comment: I just read this other post regarding how you have to use this.Dispatcher.Invoke when accessing xaml in custom made methods rather than event and it solved the issue. :) Really appreciate help of you all though. And @SoroneHaetir, my bad actually, i was running it without debugging and hence it was crashing rather than showing the error message. I am new to this stuff so, but hey that is a really good way to track your problem down by running it in debugger. :) Thanks!

Comment: @Shrey can you supply a link to what found you the answer for record keeping. Also genuinely curious. Thanks

Comment: Yes for sure @Jamin. Here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732709/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it

Comment: I have also updated changes in my question description above that i made in my method to make it work. :)

Comment: You don‘t update your question in these cases. You post an answer.

Comment: How bizarre - I marked this question as a duplicate with the correct solution 5 hours ago, and someone removed that comment. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access a control from a non-UI thread. You have to use [a dispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to marshal it back to the UI thread:

```
displaymsg.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => displaymsg.Items.Add(msg));
```

You can also fire and forget if you don‘t want to wait for the result:

```
displaymsg.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => displaymsg.Items.Add(msg));
```

Comment: This was very helpful answer. Thanks @Sefe :)