# Retrieving a dp value from another task

Tags: c#

I'm using a dp, and I created 2 tasks.

In task1, I new a `TestClass`. In task2, I want to get Num value, but got error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in WindowsBase.dll
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll but was not handled in user code
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

Note, they must be in different thread for some reason. Actually there are 3 threads, I just made a sample to reproduce it.

[image]
[image]
namespace WpfApp1
{
/// 
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// 
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
public MainWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

```
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var task1 = new Task(Test1);
            task1.Start();

            var task2 = new Task(Test2);
            task2.Start();

            task1.Wait();
            task2.Wait();
        }

        private TestClass another = null;
        private AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        private void Test1()
        {
            another = new TestClass();
            autoResetEvent.Set();
        }

        private void Test2()
        {
            //Task.Delay(1000);
            autoResetEvent.WaitOne();

            int k = 0;
            k = another.Num;
        }

    }

    public class TestClass : DependencyObject
    {
        public int Num
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)GetValue(NumProperty);
            }
            set { SetValue(NumProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NumProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Num", typeof(int), typeof(TestClass), new PropertyMetadata(10));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732709/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it)

Comment: No, the mentioned answers are relating to ui thread. I have 3 threads now.

Comment: *The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it* -> you cannot access uit objects from the non-ui thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you *cannot* access a dependency property from any other thread than the one on which the `DependencyObject` was created on.

It's the `VerifyAccess` method in the [base class implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs,fdcfbb9383a20825,references) that throws the `InvalidOperationException` and there is nothing you can do about this (apart from making sure that you only access the dependency property from the dispatcher thread of course).