# C# wpf unable to start animation from background worker

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I'm creating simple elevator simulation app in wpf code behind and c#.
dotnet version: 7.1
dotnet framework version 4.8

I created a ScaleTransform animation in a thread and it animates the doors, there is a button when clicked, it either closes or opens both the doors.

i.e.
btn.Click += (.....) => { OpenLeftDoor(); OpenRightDoor() }

this works fine however, I need to do this when the lift moves to next floor and that is done via background worker.
so I need to open both the doors from the background worker.

following is the code for animating:

```
 public void OpenLeftDoor()
        {
            var anim = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(animationDuration));
            leftDoorAnimation.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => leftDoorAnimation.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, anim));
        }

        public void OpenRightDoor()
        {
            var anim = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(animationDuration));
            rightDoorAmination.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => rightDoorAmination.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, anim));
        }
```

following is the code that runs on a background thread and tries to open the door:

```
while (!Schedule.IsEmpty)
            {
                if (LiftState.Direction == LiftDirection.Up && !IsLastFloor(LiftState.CurrentFloor))
                {
                    MoveLiftUp();
                    if (Schedule.Dequeue(LiftState.CurrentFloor))
                    {
                        LiftState.Status = LiftStatus.Paused;
                        LiftEventsEmitter.EmitMotionStateChange(LiftStatus.Paused, LiftDirection.Up);
                        LiftState.CurrentFloor.LogArrival();
                        Thread.Sleep(oneSec);
                        LiftState.CurrentFloor.OpenDoor();
                        Thread.Sleep(threeSec);
                        LiftState.CurrentFloor.CloseDoor();
                        LiftState.Status = LiftStatus.Moving;
                    }
                }
}
```

The LiftState.CurrentFloor.OpenDoor()
is a function :
OpenDoor() { OpenLeftDoor(); OpenRightDoor()}

however, this time I get an error that says **calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.**

however the same code works when the button is clicked.
besides there are other controls like Labels whose text is updated using the same approach.
i.e. label.Dispatcher.Invoke()

I googled and searched different stackoverflow threads regarding this error, but all of them suggest the same approach which does not seem to work in my case.

Comment: leftDoorAnimation and rightDoorAnimation is ScaleTransform object.

Comment: Did you search for the error message? There is lots of material regarding this problem, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732709/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it

Comment: @KlausGütter yeah, same answer as I already used in here i.e. using the Dispatcher.Invoke()

Comment: In other projects I used to use the galasoft.mvvmlight.messaging functionality to send a message from the background thread to the ui to kick off a ui function (like taking a screenshot, etc)