How to Redirect standard output from my NET 4.8 application
I am trying to redirect standard output from my Net 4.8 application.  This is the code I am using:
private  async void button_Export(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var item in myList.Items)
        {
            await RunProcessAsync(@"MyProcess.exe", item.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

private Task RunProcessAsync(string fileName, string arguments)
{
             
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;  
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            // handling output
            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Data != null)
                {
                    lineCount++;
                    output.Append("\n[" + lineCount + "]: " + e.Data);
                    // MessageBox.Show($"output: {output}"); //this works
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(output.ToString()); //this throws an error
                }
            };
            process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Data != null)
                {
                    // Handle standard error here
                }
            };

            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            process.WaitForExit(); // Wait for the process to exit
        }
    });
}

The MessageBox.Show() displays the desired output  but if send to richTextBox1, I get an error.
“the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.”
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Many thanks for finding the answer  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732709/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it)-Worked great!!
